# Let's define $S$ the subset of $\mathbb{R}$ of the numbers which contains the digit $7$. Is $S$ connected?

Tags: general-topology

> Let's define $S$ the subset of $\mathbb{R}$ of the numbers which contains the digit $7$. Is $S$ connected?

My belief is no, but I really cannot do any drawf of a decent proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are precisely the intervals. Thus if $S$ were connected, it must be an interval. But clearly $S$ is unbounded above and below, thus we must have $S= \mathbb{R}$. This is absurd.

Comment: Consider the open interval $(0.7, 0.8)$. This is a non-degenerate interval in which every number contains at least one digit $7$. So I can't get your statement "Every non-degenerate interval contains a number without the digit $7$"

Comment: Good point. I edited my post to circumvent this problem.

Comment: However I can understand it is not an interval and so I can can conclude it is not connected

Comment: Yes, I edited my post to see why this is the case.